# Can any user change uid/gid using setuid()/setgid()?

Tags: unix

or only root can?

I want to change the uid/gid of a non-root from a .sh script
by calling setuid/setgid. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

per default, only root can use setuid/setgid. maybe with selinux or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no setuid or setgid command available to [sh(1)](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sh.html), the Bourne shell. Actually [setuid(2)](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setuid.html) and setgid() are system calls only available in  programming languages such as C or Perl(and in just about any code except shell scripts). Even when available, the calls have limited utility when called as non-root users.  These calls give no privilege not already available to the real user.

There are also the file modes setuid([setuid bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) set) or setgid (meaning setgid bit set); but those are only for binary executables, not (normally) for sh scripts*.

For ordinary users to run a command as a different user without reentering a password, even from a script, use the [sudo(8)](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/sudoers.man.html) command.  Sudo requires configuration by a system administrator.

There are other ways of acting as a different user; but all involve calling an external executable which has been blessed(had the [setuid bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) set) by the super user, or by having some other user's process perform a task.

**See Also**
[sudo(8)](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/sudoers.man.html)  The sudo command
[setuid(2)](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setuid.html)  The setuid system call

[setuid bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid)  The access mode
*[Setuid on Shell Scripts](http://www.tuxation.com/setuid-on-shell-scripts.html)
[How can I get setuid shell scripts to work?](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part4/section-7.html)

*Related commands*
[sh(1)](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sh.html), [sg(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sg), [su(1)](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Guide_to_Unix/Explanations/Becoming_Root)